# is swift integer literal not include bitwise expression?

Tags: swift

I am learning swift OptionSet, and I write this code and I get a compile error

> "error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to specified type 'Number'"

it happens when I init `one` with `1 << 0`

```swift
struct Number: OptionSet, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let zero: Number = 0
    static let one: Number = 1 << 0
    static let two: Number = 1 << 1
    static let three: Number = 1 << 2

    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        rawValue = integerLiteral
    }

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}
```

if I use decimal instead of bitwise expression, everything is good

```
struct Number: OptionSet, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let zero: Number = 0
    static let one: Number = 1 
    static let two: Number = 2
    static let three: Number = 4

    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        rawValue = integerLiteral
    }

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}
```

Please let me know why!!!

Comment: (1 << 1) is not a literal, you could use 0b10 or Number(rawValue: (1 << 1)) instead

Comment: @Cyberbeni Is that a constant expression? I would actually suppose them to behave the same. It's far from being obvious why these are different.

Comment: Why "far from being obvious"? Literals are a subset of constant expressions. The protocol allows literals to be converted to the conforming type, so obviously not every constant expression will be able to be converted. @Sulthan

Comment: @Sulthan "Literals" are very narrow. Literally only literal forms, like `0xABCD`, `0b1010`, `123`, etc. The intent of `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` is to make Integer's "preferential treatment" over custom types like `MyInt` be non-preferential, and available to custom types. It's not intended to be a way to define implicit casts for arbitrary expressions.

Comment: @Sweeper I understand it, but it is confusing for many programmers. Most programmers don't even know what things like literal, expression, statement really mean. Then you look at the code and you have to wonder why two similar assignments work differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

This doesn't work because what you have is a constant expression (an expression whose subexpressions are exclusively other constant expressions, or literals), which itself is not literal.

"Literals" are very narrow: literally only literal forms, like `0xABCD`, `0b1010`, `123`, etc. The intent of `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` is to make Integer's "preferential treatment" over custom types like `MyInt` be non-preferential, and available to custom types. It's not intended to be a way to define implicit casts for arbitrary expressions.

### The straight-forward fix

To fix this, you can either explicitly wrap your expressions like `Number(rawValue: 1 << 2)`.

### The "clever" fix

This works, though it's not typical, and I wouldn't recommend it. I add it here just because I think it's kinda interesting.

You can actually achieve this by making a `<<` operator of type (Number, Number) -> Number`. The expression`1 << 2`could then be evaluated as`Number(integerLiteral: 1) << Number(integerLiteral: 2)`, resulting in a`Number`.

Pro tip: If you don't define any initializes in the main declaration of the struct, and instead define them in extensions (such as for conformance to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`), you get to keep the "default memberwise initializer`, in this case,`Number.init(rawValue:)`, that the compiler automatically synthesizes for you.

```
struct Number {
    let rawValue: Int
}

extension Number {
    static func << (lhs: Number, rhs: Number) -> Number {
        return Number(rawValue: lhs.rawValue << rhs.rawValue)
    }
}

extension Number: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        rawValue = integerLiteral
    }
}

extension Number: OptionSet {
    static let zero: Number = 0
    static let one: Number = 1 << 0
    static let two: Number = 1 << 1
    static let three: Number = 1 << 2
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I learned a lot.
I still get one question.
Why I can use constant expression to init a Int like ```let a = 1 << 1```
I see Int type conform to ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral too, is it because Int reload "<<" operator like your clever fix?

Comment: Well you can use a constant expression to init an `Int`: `let x: Int = 123`. Though I think what you probably meant is "Why can't I use a constant expression of type `Int` to initialize something that conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`?" And the answer is "because while integer literals are examples of constant expressions, not all constant expressions are integer literals."

Comment: Oh you edited your question. `let a = 1 << 1` works because there's a `<<` operator defined with type `(Int, Int) -> Int`. Each of those 1s is an `Int`, initialized from a literal because `Int` conforms for `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, Those are then passed as arguments to the `<<` operand, resulting in a `Int` result.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much